# mappedBy issue with Ebean/Play framework

Tags: mysql, orm, playframework-2.0, ebean, playframework-2.3

I try to create a link between two tables : `User` and `Notifications` 
The `Notifications` tables should have:

1. Id (int)
2. User_Id (int)
3. List < User >

I need to clarify my goal. In my app, a user ask something to several others, using notifications tables. So that, we can know:

1. Who is the user who asks the question (User_Id)
2. To whow users the question is aked (List< User >)

**User**

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="notification_fk")
    public Notifications notification; 
}
```

**Notifications**

```
@Entity
public class Notifications extends Model{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id; 
    public User user; 
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="notifications")
    public List<User> asked_users = new ArrayList<User>();
}
```

But I get the following error:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error on
>   models.Notifications.asked_users  Can not find mappedBy property
>   [user] in [models.User]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `mappedBy` you need to use the name of the ***existing*** oposite field, and it's `notification` in your case - without **'s'** at the end.

Comment: Several question. Why without an "s"? Also, by just deleting the S, I only have an ID field in my notifiactions table.

Comment: without s because name of field in your User model is `notification` NOT `notifications`

Comment: Oh ... Right ... Do you have any idea why I have only an ID field in Notification table?